# Is it possible to schedule Logins in a Firebase app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

As a Computer Science student, I was recently introduced to process scheduling and how the processes are commuted to share the systems resources.

I am considering creating an iOS app which uses users position to notify them about nearby events and I'll use Firebase frameworks. The thing is, this is more of a hobby for now and I am not willing to spend any money unless I see the app growing and I would like to know if it is possible to commute user Logins so that no more than 100 users are logged in at a time and so that users don't have to log in every time they open the app. Is this possible or even legal?

```
pseudo-code

maxUsers = 100
currentUsers = 0



if(user_requests_login){
    if(currentUsers < maxUsers){
        logIn()
    currentUsers++
}
else
    wait_on_logout    //semaphore like wait (until currentUsersDecreases)
}

if(user_is_idle){
    logOut()            //keeping track of users info so that we can logIn again without users typing in credentials (like a cookie?)
    currentUsers--
    //another user can now logIn 
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty vague question and really not appropriate for this forum. It seems you want to limit the number of users to 100 and also allow users to stay logged in even if the app is not opened? What legal aspect are you concerned about? I would suggest exploring Firebase and writing up some code to attempt to do what you want then let us know where you get stuck so we can help. Please review [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more importantly [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jay I've added pseudo-code to clarify my question, even though my question has already been answered! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I am not sure it truly answered your question. You asked how to cap your user logins to 100 and the answer states *There is no limit to how many users can be signed in to Firebase*. While there is a limit of 100 users connecting to the *Realtime Database* on the free plan (currently). I've been told that's going to change to 116 in a week so you shouldn't rely on that (just an example). Also, Firebase doesn't know if a user is idle and it has no server side logic so your logic has to be contained in your app to determine if a user can attach to to the Firebase Database or not.

Comment: @jay How could I implement that logic? There is a method that returns wether a app has gone to background right? Could i use that as a green light to disconnect that user from the db and connect another one? The point of the app is to be user managed, i.e. user1 can drop a pin on a map and if that pin is closer than 'x' meters to user2, then user2 gets notified. DB access would be made only to check proximity of users so there would only be a critical section bordered by "setting a pin" and "get nearby users" in which i would have to implement that logic

Comment: Firebase is a good solution as when a pin is dropped, other users will be notified of that event via an Observe and can then determine if they are within a range of that pin. However, all of that logic needs to be on the client side. And yes, you can know if an app is in the background but disconnecting the user at that time may not be the best user experience. i.e. If they want to quickly check their mail while waiting for someone else to drop a pin. You should really take some time and write some code with Firebase to get a feel of it, then come back with any specific coding questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem confused about the limits on Firebase's free/spark plan. There is no limit to how many users can be signed in to Firebase, on the free plan or either of the paid plans.

But there is a limit on how many users can be connected to the Firebase Realtime Database at any one moment. On the free/spark plan that limit is 100.

Comment: Oh thats great! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to schedule logins in firebase apps. it will depend on your app logic. you set a maximumUser variable and check with that before signing a user in and when the maximum is reach, disable the signin function or button.
you can also use sessions to keep track of the users currently loged in

Comment: thanks! I was thinking about using preemption on logged in users so that briefly I could logout a user to let others in (do something) and later log that blocked user back in! But i guess Franks answer made it clear that i dont need to. Thanks again!

Comment: okay... that was a good answer to your question then, firebase already set limits based on the account